# Google Firebase iOS build uploads file to storage on Mac, but triggers StorageException when running on iPad

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I have built an iOS app using Unity (2019.4) and the Google Firebase SDK. In this scene, I take data in from a BLE device, write it to a .csv, and upload this .csv to Firebase Storage. When I run this app in the Unity editor on my Mac (OS 10.15.7), the .csv file uploads properly. But, when I build this script to my iPad Pro (14.4.2), I get a StorageException:

> Autoconnected Player Failed to upload because System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: No object exists at the desired reference

The coroutine that manages the upload of my .csv is here:

```
private IEnumerator UploadCSV()
    {
        string filepath = GetComponent<CSVManager>().WriteCSV();
        fbS = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        var CSVReference = fbS.GetReferenceFromUrl(path);
        var uploadTask = CSVReference.PutFileAsync(filepath);
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => uploadTask.IsCompleted);

        if (uploadTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to upload because {uploadTask.Exception}");
            yield break;
        }

        var getUrlTask = CSVReference.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => getUrlTask.IsCompleted);

        if (getUrlTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to get a download url with {getUrlTask.Exception}");
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Download from {getUrlTask.Result}");

    }
```

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days. I am confused because it seems as though the issue lies within CSVReference, but I can't understand why the script would work properly on my Mac but not on my iPad. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, I was able to work around the error by switching from the PutFileAsync() upload function to PutBytesAsync(). In order to do this, I had to change my local data structure from a .csv file to a byte array. Once I made this switch, I was able to upload a .csv file to my firebase storage bucket.

I still do not understand why I was getting the PutFileAsync() error only on my iPad. But this solution works for now.